# Quotient of ring $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Just wanted to obtain quick clarification on this question: is $(\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z)/(3\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$?

And would it be correct to call $3\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$ an ideal of $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Both statements correct.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Thank you very much.

Comment: The third isomorphism theorem says $$(G⁄K)⁄(N⁄K)≅G⁄N.$$ So let $G=\Bbb Z$, $K=9\Bbb Z$ and $N=3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: And the same is true for rings and ideals (sorry, I thought of groups first, but it is about rings). So $(R/I)/(J/I)\cong R/J$, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_C_(rings)), Theorem $C$ for rings.